# How can I replace url field by using .net Regex.Replace?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I'm developing some .net app.
And then I have some trouble in using Regex.
I want to change url field by using Regex.Replace.

This is my code.
I know that this do not work collectly.

```
var originStr = "<a href='aaa'/><a href='bbb'/><a href='ccc'/><a href='ddd'/><a href='eee'/><a href='fff'/>";
var convStr = Regex.Replace(originStr, "(<a href=').*('/>)", "http://hello.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

you want this?

```
    var originStr = "<a href='aaa'/><a href='bbb'/><a href='ccc'/><a href='ddd'/><a href='eee'/><a href='fff'/>";
    var convStr = Regex.Replace(originStr, "<a href='[^']+'/>", "<a href='http://hello.com'/>");
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the result that I want to get.

 "<a href='http://hello.com'/><a href='http://hello.com'/><a href='http://hello.com'/><a href='http://hello.com'/><a href='http://hello.com'/><a href='http://hello.com'/>"